# XML filtering using getelementsbytagname

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse a xml file using the below program but wondering why the `getFirstChild()` is blank while printing...

The `nodelist` contains all the `employee` nodes and I am processing each node and trying to get the `firstchild` and `lastchild`..

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee emplid="1111" type="admin">
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Watson</lastname>
        <age>30</age>
        <email>johnwatson@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee emplid="2222" type="admin">
        <firstname>Sherlock</firstname>
        <lastname>Homes</lastname>
        <age>32</age>
        <email>sherlock@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

java program:

```
package XML;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class XMLTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        DocumentBuilderFactory builderfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmldocument = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("c:/employees.xml")));
            NodeList node = xmldocument.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
            System.out.println("node length="+node.getLength());
            for (int temp = 0; temp < node.getLength(); temp++){
                System.out.println("First Child = " +node.item(temp).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                System.out.println("Last Child = " +node.item(temp).getLastChild().getNodeValue());
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely due to the whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks etc.) that comes through as text nodes in the list as well as the elements.

When working with java's XML DOM I tend to write a helper like [this](https://github.com/indicee/Indicee-BI-API-Java-Library/blob/master/src/com/indicee/api/util/XmlHelper.java) as it's pretty tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentBuilderFactory controls the handling of whitespaces try:

```
builderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
```

Hope it helps!